# why CHAR dont have padding in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
I am looking at the difference about CHAR vs VARCHAR
```

it is said CHAR is fixed length and VARCHAR is variable length. When we insert data, CHAR field will have padding, But today I did a small test in MYSQL(version5.6.40), I did not find CHAR field have padding

```
mysql> create table temp(
-> City CHAR(10),
-> Street VARCHAR(10));

select length(city),length(street) from temp;

length(city) | length(street)
|         4  |              6 |
```

Suppose length(city) should get 10? who can clarify here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The padding used to store a `CHAR` is transparently removed when you read the value. The SQL Server sees the padding and goes "that's padding; the user doesn't want that" and so doesn't give it to you. It's very clever.

Some implementations use null bytes. Others (iirc Microsoft's T-SQL, though this is probably just my imagination) use `0x20` bytes. What's important to note is that all of that space is used up, regardless of whether you're using it to store any data. If your strings are sometimes `2000000` characters long but are usually around `6` characters long, use a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Really thanks! is there any way to verify all characters used when we store in CHAR field?  I saw someone posted length(City) result is 10.

Comment: @user8196549 I don't understand what you're trying to say. You should ignore the concept of "padding"; that's what we call in the trade an "implementation detail". Just know that a `CHAR(10)` lets you store text _up to_ a maximum length of `10`; get your head around that, and _then_ try to work out how it works. It's a bit pointless trying to check whether 10 characters-worth-of-space is used up, because that has no bearing on what's stored in your database.